# Can we get id of child linear layout by setting listener on parent linear layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have one linear layout and inside it there are many child layouts. I don't want to put click listener on each and every child layout. I had set ids of child layout such that i can call respective activity using Class.forName().

So basically i am looking for a more productive way than putting click listener on each linear layout. Is there any way to meet this issue?

Comment: A listener for what, exactly?

Comment: Click listener for changing acitivity. Parent linear layout contains bunch of icons which takes user to corresponding acitivity.

Comment: You need to put that in your question. There are a lot more listener interfaces than just `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and i had edited my question. Do you think what i want is possible in android?

Comment: And what's the problem with setting a listener to each layout? You can iterate through all children of your linear layout in one `for` cycle and set the same `OnClickListener` to all of them. Clicked view will be available as an argument of `OnClickListener.onClick(View view)` method, and you can simply get ID of clicked view by `view.getId()` and choose the proper activity.

Comment: I know that but i was looking for a more efficient way as android always surprise with better alternative. But it seems that it is not possible.

Comment: I was thinking that I can put listener on parent linear layout and onClick(View view) i can get child linear layout view somehow.